# Set a parent property of a QML item from a QQuickView object

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have 3 files (along with `CMakeLists.txt` and `qrc`):

- `main.cpp` - C++
- `BDialog.qml` - a "base" for my dialog (contains the property definition)
- `BEditorDialog.qml` - a dialog with a label

They contain:

```
// main.cpp

#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QQuickView view;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty( "myText", "WOW!" ); // expected to work but doesn't

    view.setSource( QUrl( "qrc:/BEditorDialog.qml" ) );

    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

---

```
//BDialog.qml

import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    // This property I want to set from C++
    property string myText
}
```

---

```
// BEditorDialog.qml

import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

BDialog {
    id: root

    Label {
        id: label
        text: root.myText // doesn't work
    }
}
```

If I assign initial value to the `myText` property:

```
property string myText: "MEH!"
```

this initial value is displayed, but how to assign it from C++ ? I suspect I should use the `setInitialProperties` member function, but I have only Qt 5.12 installed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I confirm: the `setInitialProperties` member function works here. Is there an alternative in Qt 5.12 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up context and object. You're setting the property `"myText"` on the [QQmlContext](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html) which is not the root object of your application. To get the root object you can use [rootObject()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickview.html#rootObject) on your `QQuickView` and get a `QQuickItem` back. On that you can call [setProperty()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty).

This works

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/BEditorDialog.qml"));
    // First set the source and then access the rootObject, 
    // otherwise it isn't created yet
    view.rootObject()->setProperty("myText", "WOW!");

    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I' should've read the documentation very carefully.

Comment: BTW, But may be a bit off topic. I see the error `cannot call method of null` if I try the same with a property of type `QtObject`. Though eventually it is assigned a pointer, I suspect that initially the instance is created with null (because `setSource` goes first). I don't see this error when using the `setInitialProperties` *before* `setSource`.

Comment: I tried using a `QObject` in the `setProperty()` function, but clang complains, because there is no conversion from `QObject` to `QVariant`. What did you actually provide as the second parameter?

Comment: `QVariant::fromValue( pObject )` where `pObject` has a type of `QObject*`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of iam_peter, you can actually also use the context property in the way you have set it, but with the warning that a name collision is present. This might be more appropriate in bigger projects (it seems here you only want a way to show a dialog from C++ and be done with it)

Given a proper name, say 'myDialogText', you can use it as follows:

```
// BEditorDialog.qml

import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

BDialog {
    id: root

    Label {
        id: label
        text: myDialogText
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I found it also, thank you. But I had to actually remove this property from the `BDialog.qml` otherwise it didn't work. What Qt version are you using here ?

Comment: yes, that's the other way to resolve the name collision ;-) I'm still on 5.11.3, but it shouldn't be too different across versions